# Display a default value in form fields Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How does django display the default value in a textfield to form.

```
<input type="text" name="{{ form.username}}" value="{{ costumer.username}}"><p>
```

it shows a textfield follow by costumer.username in browser, I want to have the username as default value in the textfield, How can i do that?

Comment: what is customer ? is it another object

Comment: yeah , they both are objects and have been passed in a dictionary to a template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use initial parameter to a form:

```
form = Form(initial={'username': costumer.username})
```

and to display input in template you need just this:

```
{{ form.username }}<br/>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

Comment: I need to add a custom class to the field. Any way to write custom HTML and put the default there? `<input value='{{ form.username.initial }}>` doesn't work and `form.username.value` neither.

Comment: @CGFoX i think you talk about customizing field widget (class is passed to widget attrs dict) - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances

Answer (score 2):

In your view:

```
myForm = MyForm(initial={'username': costumer.username })
```

and in the template:

```
{{myForm.username|safe}}
```

Should do the trick.